# Why don't we always use the best encryption technologies?

Tags: database, security, encryption

I'm exploring currently the safe aspects of Java. Of course one of the first things I looked up, was the whole decoding point.

**Mentioned decryption technologies**

After some time of studying I learned some thing about following cryptography technologies:

1. MD5
2. SHA
3. PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

**Why am I asking this question ?**

I know that roughly speaking SHA1 is safer than MD5, with PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 being the safest. But now I have to ask myself, why in some applications an encryption like MD5 or SHA1 is still used, whereas in this case PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 is more secure? I am of course aware that the chance to take advantage of the best technology comes only in rare cases (reduction of brute force speed / risk of collision).

But in spite of everything the implementation time is a little bit longer and in return you get a more secure encryption.

**My final question**

In short, my question is why not all applications always use the best encryption technology, even if they don't necessarily need it? I mean the only drawback is that it takes a little bit longer to implement.

**In addition**

I don't think that the loss of speed is a reason, to not use the best encryption technologies.

> The goal is to make the hash function slow enough to impede attacks, but still fast enough to not cause a noticeable delay for the user. From [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/security/how-to-generate-secure-password-hash-md5-sha-pbkdf2-bcrypt-examples/)

Comment: 1) Hashing is not encryption. 2) Not every application of cryptographic hashes has to do with passwords. 3) Developers generally don't care about security unless forced to do so -- it's hard and nobody likes you for getting it right, they only hate you for getting it wrong. (There are exceptions, of course.) Outdated, insecure and badly copy pasted code is very common. This is true even on the level of the OS and libraries for languages (just look at how it took for TLS 1.2 or even 1.1 to get widespread support, despite the age and the big, known security holes of earlier versions).

Comment: The line "nobody likes you for getting it right, they only hate you for getting it wrong" spoke for itself. Good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of resons comes to my mind:

1. Lack of knowledge - one do not know enough about cryptography to write good code (should I choose PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1, PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512, [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), [Argon2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2)?)
2. Legacy systems - hashed values can't be unhashed, thus hashed passwords can't be converted to new cryptography scheme
3. No library /available/supported/NIST compliant/ etc. by the operating system

Comment: So it's more like, many people don't know enough about cryptography so they are just going the safe why by choosing a common technology ? 
Irrespective of the fact that there are more suitable possibilities.